# I come from the deepest layers

Tags: riddle

I figured I'd have a go at a (hopefully) nice riddle.

> I come from the deepest layers,
>   Yet am seen in the highest.
>   I'm made of nothing but seas,
>   But judged on only four of them.
>   I propose you think carefully about your answer,
>   I'm more likely to scratch your reputation than the other way around.

Who/what am I?

Note: The last lines are just part of the riddle. No need to be afraid I'll downvote every incorrect answer!

Edit: Two additional lines, since they were too nice to be left out:

> Collectors and criminals covet me yet can live without,
>   But there's one group here that cannot be separated from me.

Comment: Bit easy...  But sometimes easy just means you're not being more convoluted than need be for a good riddle.  I like it... :)  +1

Comment: Hmm, I only just thought of a nice opportunity to use the SE moderators as part of the riddle... Too bad I missed it :(

Comment: Add it as a hint.  No harm in it.  It's not changing the original riddle and might be useful/fun for anyone coming to this later.

Comment: @BrentHackers Took a while, but I've added two lines! Maybe you can add explanations for them as well?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe this is

> Diamond

I come from the deepest layers,

> -of the earth

Yet am seen in the highest.

> they can be mined close to the surface

I'm made of nothing but seas,

> Carbon

But judged on only four of them.

> Cut, Color, Clarity and Carat.

I propose you think carefully about your answer,

> Marriage association

I'm more likely to scratch your reputation than the other way around.

> Hard rock...

Comment: Geez, I barely had time to refresh the page before you found the correct answer... For the second line I had a different explanation in mind, though yours also works. Also, there's one more hint hidden away in one of the lines... I wonder if you can find it!

Comment: @Lolgast That it then?   Good puzzle by the way.  Lots of riddles on here are more suitable for hard-core puzzlers.  Nice to see some beginner ones that everyone can enjoy now and then.

Comment: Nice work! Certainly enough for the checkmark, I'll award it soon (for some more shameless view-attraction). Though, of course, I'd still like to see if you can find the explanation for the second line I had in mind initially. Also, thanks for the compliment!

Comment: @Lolgast  Maybe a reference to sparkling stars or something?  I'm struggling with that one...

Comment: Maybe the highest mean all the rich people in this world ?

Comment: @Skyvask Good find! To be a little more exact, I was talking about the high layers of society.

Comment: @Lolgast sometimes, i just dont find the words to exprime myself, learning english on internet has some weakness

Comment: @Skyvask No worries! My comment was meant as a little bit of explanation to your answer, and not a correction or something like that.

Comment: Technically there are synthetic diamonds also which do not follow the puzzle. So my answer is natural diamonds :)

Comment: @Skyvask: If you've learnt your English from the internet, you're doing very well :-) One hint: "m'exprimer" = "to express myself" (and a few other verbs that are "---primer" in French become "---press" in English - eg opprimer, réprimer, comprimer etc.)